# GRASS GIS - V.VOL.RST avoid segmentation (paneling)

Tags: grass-gis, interpolation, voxel

In order to reduce the segmentation effect where the interpolation appears to have different square regions, is this due to segment that are too small (segmax?).

Is the solution to avoid this to increase the segment size (which increases the run time)?

What should be the ratio of npmin and mpmax vs segmax as these two parameters need to be greater than segmax?

The default setting for the module is 50 for segmax, 200 for npmin, and 700 for mpmax.

Comment: Can you please edit and add the error message?

Comment: there is no error message as it just visible when vewing the data.  See link here for screenshot     https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/6509/M0aSyH.png

Comment: I solved this by interpolating 2d layers and restacked them into one 3D raster

Comment: Great - please add it as a real answer to your question.